# SCPlugin icons and menu

Tags: macos, svn, scp

I installed SCPlugin on my mac for subversion. It works fine but I don't see the icons show status of my files. And I don't have SCPlugin's options in my right click menu bar. Any idea how to fix these?

Comment: Which version of OS X you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you read the website carefully they say it will work but they dont have context menu(menu bar after right click) or badging (icons you are talking about).

Comment: Thanx, I saw it but in the screenshots it has context menu and icons.

Comment: Look properly to screen shots they are from 10.4 OS. I have used myself scplugin but on 10.5.